# R data suppression that ignores non-integers

Tags: r

I am trying to suppress all values in my data frame that are less than 5.
`data[data < 5] <- NA`
For the most part this works fine. However I also have some values that are categorical age groups "0-19" "20-24" and so on. I guess R is doing the subtraction and removing these as well. Is there a way to do this that ignores any value that isn't an integer?

Edit:  Some dummy data as an example:

```
dummydata<-as.data.frame(rbind(c('0-19','4','5'),c('20-24','6','1')))
> dummydata
     [,1]    [,2] [,3]
[1,] "0-19"  "4"  "5" 
[2,] "20-24" "6"  "1"   
dummydata[dummydata < 5] <- NA
> dummydata
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] NA   NA   "5" 
[2,] NA   "6"  NA
```

Desired output:

```
     [,1]    [,2] [,3]
[1,] "0-19"  NA  "5" 
[2,] "20-24" "6"  NA
```

Comment: It would help to see some example data. I don't think R is doing the subtraction since for example `"5-2" < 5` is FALSE. It would be better to act on the numeric columns only, rather than the entire data frame.

Comment: Good point @neilfws. I edited with some dummy data.

Comment: Thanks, ignore my "numeric columns" comment, I'd guessed wrongly that there was a mix of all-numeric columns and character columns.

Comment: @RonakShah df (and edited as such). Though a solution that could work in either case would be ideal.

Answer (score 2):

We can first find out values that have only numbers in them (no `'-'`), turn them to numeric and if it is less than 5 change to `NA`.

```
dummydata[] <- lapply(dummydata, function(x) {
                     tmp <- grepl('^\\d+$', x)
                     x[tmp][as.numeric(x[tmp]) < 5] <- NA
                     x
               })

dummydata

#     V1   V2   V3
#1  0-19 <NA>    5
#2 20-24    6 <NA>
```